# opencart 2.3 same image for sub categories

Tags: opencart, opencart2.3

I am using **opencart 2.3** and in category page, all sub categories have same image. Title is different, in backend and database images are different.

Removed everything from `/image/cache` with no effect.

Tried to add `$image` into `$data['categories']` array, in `controller/product/category.php`  but is the same.

This is my code from `<theme>/product/category.tpl`

```
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>" /><p><?php echo $category['name']; ?></p></a>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Can't find nothing else to fix this. Will be very appreciate, if you can help.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding this:

```
'thumb' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_category_width'), $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_category_height'))
```

to `$data['categories']` array.

:)